# How to handle per-resource (fine grained) permissions in OAuth?

Tags: oauth2, oauth

I'm designing an app architecture using OAuth 2.0. I have a separate *Resource Server* and *Authorization Server*. The latter keeps a database of users and the scopes available to them.

Now, my question is: **How and where to store/model fine-grained, per-resource permissions?**

I'm talking about a scenario similar to what happens in a file sharing app, say Dropbox, where **user can choose which files to share with which other users**. How to model this in context of OAuth?

Notably, in my case some users may exist *purely in the Authorization Server database* (the *Resource Server* doesn't know about them at all). Let's call them "read-only users"; in *AS* they would have access to a scope of `read_files_shared_to_me`. And thus, that scope is the grant/token that my *Client App* displays to the *Resource Server* when asking for a particular resource (file). Now, how should I track which files are shared to which users, in the framework of OAuth (2.0)?

- **If it is responsibility of the *Resource Server***, then how should it store the list of "allowed" users, if the users exist only in *Authorization Server*? Should the *RS* use the ["token introspection endpoint"](https://oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/) of *AS* to drill down what particular user is asking, and store a list of "allowed users" per resource ("ACL")?
- **If it is responsibility of *Authorization Server***, then how should it pass the information about "resources available to this user" to the *RS*? From what I understand, "scopes" are rather general, they correspond to "roles/groups", not concrete fine-grained resources, so putting a list of resource IDs in a "scope" field of Authorization Grant / Access Token doesn't seem OK?

---

<sup>*1*</sup> *After some further research, I found a [2011 thread with similar question on [oauth-wg] mailing list](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg08066.html). Some answers there suggest looking at "UMA". Unfortunately, the links seem to be either bit-rotten, or too vague. The [apparent main page of UMA](https://kantarainitiative.org/confluence/display/uma/Home) seems huge and still unclear to me. Also it's not clear to me if it's still relevant and up-to-date in 2018. Googling further on UMA I couldn't find helpful results. If "use UMA" is what you'd like to write as an answer, please try to explain a bit more on how I should apply it. Also, do you know of any concrete services using UMA for this purpose?*

Comment: `How, how should I track which files are shared to which users, in the framework of OAuth?`This is not Auth Server business. You are misunderstanding the role of the Auth Server. Auth server only provide consumers with Identity and token validations. Whatever you send back to the consumer, should provide info enough for the RS to decide if the user can read or not a shared file. And only the RS know where these files are at. And only the RS know what the hell is a shared file. Auth Servers are mere security guards at the doors of the Pub. They don't need to know what's going on inside.

Comment: @Laiv So if I understand correctly, you suggest that "this is the responsibility of RS"? (Or did I misunderstand?) If yes, please suggest your answers to the appropriate bullet point in my question, namely: *"**If it is responsibility of the Resource Server**, then how should it..."*

Comment: My intention with the previous comment was giving you some hints for you to have something to start with. Right now I'm at work and I can not write down a proper (detailed) answer.

Comment: More hints `then how should it store the list of "allowed" users, if the users exist only in Authorization Server?` Authorization Server do know nothing about users. It might know something about `Accounts`. RS might be able to retrieve the User from the Account (or principal) provided by the AS.

Comment: @Laiv But in basic OAuth 2.0, RS doesn't know anything about Account, it only knows some Scopes, AFAIU...

Comment: But yet, the RS can hold data to correlate Accounts and Users. At least is how I implement social logins with Oauth. The AS issues tokens and validate them when they are requested to do, but they don't get involved in the matters of the business logic. Authentication and Authorization are traversals of the architecture.

Comment: @Laiv Eh, unfortunately I still can't grasp what you're trying to tell me. And this comments thread is already getting too long for SE, so if you could try and flesh out a full blown "answer", it'd be super cool, but if not, then I'm just going to pass. Thanks for your good will and trying!

Answer (score 6):

<sup>*Eh, answering my own question... I followed up a bit more on UMA, and it seems to be indeed some kind of a possible solution:*</sup>

[UMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Managed_Access) seems to be a semi-official (or at least the only official-looking one I could find) extension to OAuth 2.0, adding support for "fine grained", *M:N* sharing of resources. In simple words, it allows a scenario such as:

> "Alice shares a folder of cat photos with Bob."

The [UMA spec](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/rec-uma-core.html) itself is, um... somewhat of a bucketload of wordy formalese, as specs of this world like to be; but if you squeeze it to get to the juice, it suddenly starts to show as actually quite approachable, in my opinion. The core underlying "trick" I'd say is in an idea that:

> "**It should be AS's responsibility** (to guard the access & manage individual permissions), but it would work on **opaque resource pointers provided by RS** (thus not needing to know about semantics of particular resources)."

Expanding a bit more on the idea, a "high level" architecture sketch of a possible implementation could be like below:

- *Authorization Server* must store one extra persistent table, "resource_sets", where each row represents "an opaque pointer to some concrete resource(s) in RS". [For example, a row could represent Alice's folder named: *"Rly funny CATS!!!1!1"*] The columns would need to be more or less:

  - `id` — unique row ID in the *AS*
  - `owner` — *Resource Owner* of the resources [e.g. `"alice"`]
  - `rs_id` — ID provided by *Resource Server* (the "opaque pointer")
  - `name` — human-friendly name, also provided by *RS* [e.g. `"Rly funny CATS!!!1!1"`]
  - `max_scopes` — also provided by *RS* [e.g. `"view"`, or `"view add delete"`]
  - a list of `(user, scopes)` pairs, dynamically managed by *Resource Owner* via some UI on *AS*. (This could be kept in a separate table if needed, implementation detail.) [e.g. `("bob", "view")`]
- *AS* must also expose a REST API, through which *Resource Server* can create, edit, and delete resource_sets entries (more details in the UMA spec),
- and a UI, through which *RO* can add/remove users & permissions, i.e. `(user, scopes)` pairs, to owned resource_sets (or at least some REST endpoints, so that implementer could build UI on those).
- *Resource Server* must keep a mapping of: *resource* → *rs_id*;
- when some *Client* requests a *resource* in *RS*, the *RS* must find the *rs_id*, and ask *AS* what are  allowed *scopes* for this *rs_id*, through some elaborate dance using *Access Tokens* etc.

For full details, see obviously the full spec:

***[User-Managed Access (UMA) Profile of OAuth 2.0](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/rec-uma-core.html)*** [html]

***EDIT:*** The 2.0 version of UMA spec in HTML format seems to be here, IIUC:

***[User-Managed Access (UMA) 2.0 Grant for OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/oauth-uma-grant-2.0-05.html)*** [html]

but I haven't looked into it yet, to confirm if that's indeed related.